# Is it possible to run gzserver and gzclient on separate computers?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to run gzserver on one computer while the gzclient on another one? I tried to change the GAZEBO_MASTER_URI on another computer to the IP address that the gazebo runs,  and then start the gzclient. The messages printed out show that it connects to the gazebo master but shows only an empty world on GUI.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/255/is-it-possible-to-run-gzserver-and-gzclient-on-separate-computers?/) by [Wenguo Liu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/78/wenguo-liu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-12-02**:
You now have > 16 karma, and thus voting rights. Use them wisely : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes. See [here](http://www.gazebosim.org/user_guide/started_commandlineinterface.html).
You just need to make sure that the network settings permit both machines to resolve the network names (or IP addresses) used.  Gazebo seems to borrow alot from the ROS [NetworkSetup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup), so that's a good read as well.

Also, did you set `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI`? You mentioned GAZEBO*MASTER*URI.

Finally, did the world that you used successfully spawn/load all the desired objects?

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2012-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-02**:
I'd be cautious of trying to do this over the internet though.. I haven't tried it (yet), but I would expect the network traffic to induce latency.